# Future with Timeout in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Suppose I have a function, which invokes a blocking *interruptible* operation. I would like to run it asynchronously with a timeout. That is, I would like to interrupt the function when the timeout is expired.

So I am trying to do something like that:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.Future

def launch(f: () => Unit, timeout: Int): Future[Try[Unit]] = {

  val aref = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[Thread]() 

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  Future {Thread.sleep(timeout); aref.get().interrupt} // 1
  Future {aref.set(Thread.currentThread); Try(f())}    // 2
}
```

The problem is that `aref` in (1) can be null because (2) has not set it to the current thread yet. In this case I would like to wait until `aref` is set. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: I assume so, but is there a reason not to do the `set` in a single thread and then split off two futures only after it's set?

Comment: `Future[Unit]` will already give you a `Try` value, no need to nest an additional `Try`.

Comment: @0__: agreed, but for some weird reason in the Functional Reactive Programming course on Coursera by M. Odersky and Erik Meijer, in one of the lecture videos Meijer makes one of his example functions "more robust" by making it return a `Future[Try[T]]` instead of a `Future[T]`.

Comment: @0__ thank you, I was wondering exactly that.

Comment: @ErikAllik do you know about any example where we would see a difference? / could you elaborate more on that? I tried to see some different behaviour setting timeouts and dividing by zero, but I couldn't. I've added a `Try` at the `Await` (I think that really makes a difference there, by capturing the timeout exceptions).

Comment: I'm quite convinced there is no difference; a `Future[Try[T]]` can be mapped to `Future[T]` by `fut.map(_.get)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a `CountDownLatch` you can achieve the behavior you want.  (Note that blocking (i.e. getting stuck at `await`) in lots and lots of `Future`s may lead to starvation of thread pools.)

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.Future

def launch(f: () => Unit, timeout: Int): Future[Try[Unit]] = {

  val aref = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[Thread]()
  val cdl = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(1)

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  Future {Thread.sleep(timeout); cdl.await(); aref.get().interrupt}   // 1
  Future {aref.set(Thread.currentThread); cdl.countDown(); Try(f())}  // 2
}
```

Comment: Then if `f` is completed much faster, the underlying `Thread` will still be interrupted?

Answer (score 17):

You can go for a slightly easier approach using [**Await**](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$). The `Await.result` method takes timeout duration as a second parameter and throws a `TimeoutException` on timeout.

```
try {
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  Await.result(aref, 10 seconds);
} catch {
    case e: TimeoutException => // whatever you want to do.
}
```

Comment: I guess, It does not interrupt the function, which is running asynchronously.

Comment: In order to interrupt the function I need a mechanism similar to `aref` to store the current thread. Thus we return to the original question :)

Comment: In my code `aref` is `AtomicReference` rather than a `Future`.

Comment: Yes, but I want `y` to exit as well.

Comment: You should never use Await.result in Your production code. It's a blocking function

Comment: could you please make the import of `seconds` explicit? I am not sure where this magic should come from but without some imports it doesn't work out of the box

Comment: @PeterPerháč `import scala.concurrent.duration._`

Comment: thanks! would you be so kind and add that line to your answer?

Answer (score 6):

I needed the same behavior as well, so this is how I solved it.  I basically created an object that creates a timer and fails the promise with a TimeoutException if the future hasn't completed in the specified duration.

```
package mypackage

import scala.concurrent.{Promise, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object TimeoutFuture {

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("myActorSystem")
  def apply[A](timeout: FiniteDuration)(block: => A): Future[A] = {
    val promise = Promise[A]()
    actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeout) {
      promise tryFailure new java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    }

    Future {
      try {
        promise success block
      }
      catch {
        case e:Throwable => promise failure e
      } 
    }

    promise.future
  }
}
```

Comment: where does PackagerGlobal come from?  I get a compile error... `not found: value PackagerGlobal`

Comment: Sorry about that, PackagerGlobal was an object class in my code which I forgot to remove.  I've fixed the sample above so it's clear what object you need, namely an instance of the ActorSystem

Answer (score 3):

Although you already got some answers on how to achieve it with blocking the additional thread to handle the timeout, I would suggest you to try a different way, for the reason Rex Kerr already gave. I don't exactly know, what you are doing in `f()`, but if it is I/O bound, I would suggest you to just use an asynchronous I/O library instead. If it is some kind of loop, you could pass the timeout value directly into that function and throw a `TimeoutException` there, if it exceeds the timeout. Example:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

def doSth(timeout: Deadline) = {
  for {
    i <- 0 to 10
  } yield {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    if (timeout.isOverdue)
      throw new TimeoutException("Operation timed out.")

    i
  }
}

scala> future { doSth(12.seconds.fromNow) }
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = 
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3d104456

scala> Await.result(res3, Duration.Inf)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] =
  Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> future { doSth(2.seconds.fromNow) }
res7: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = 
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@f7dd680

scala> Await.result(res7, Duration.Inf)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Operation timed out.
    at $anonfun$doSth$1.apply$mcII$sp(<console>:17)
    at $anonfun$doSth$1.apply(<console>:13)
    at $anonfun$doSth$1.apply(<console>:13)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    ...

scala> res7.value
res10: Option[scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]]] =
  Some(Failure(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Operation timed out.))
```

This will only use only 1 thread, that will be terminated after timeout + execution time of a single step.

Comment: I suppose here, that I cannot use any asynchronous I/O my function `f` performs long blocking but _interruptible_ call.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a `CountDownLatch` like this:

```
def launch(f: () => Unit, timeout: Int): Future[Try[Unit]] = {

  val aref = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[Thread]() 

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val latch = new CountDownLatch(1)
  Future {
    latch.await()
    aref.get().interrupt
  }

  Future {
    aref.set(Thread.currentThread) 
    latch.countDown()
    Try(f())
  }
}
```

Now I'm waiting forever with my call to `latch.await()`, but you could certainly change that to:

```
latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

and then wrap it with a `Try` to handle if when/if it times out.