# Await for a Sequence of Futures with timeout without failing on TimeoutException

Tags: scala, future

I have a sequence of scala Futures of same type.

I want, after some limited time, to get a result for the entire sequence while some futures may have succeeded, some may have failed and some haven't completed yet, the non completed futures should be considered failed.

I don't want to use Await each future sequentially.

I did look at this question: [Scala waiting for sequence of futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344430/scala-waiting-for-sequence-of-futures)
and try to use the solution from there, namely:

```
  private def lift[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]])(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) =
    futures.map(_.map { Success(_) }.recover { case t => Failure(t) })

  def waitAll[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]])(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) =
    Future.sequence(lift(futures))

  futures: Seq[Future[MyObject]] = ...
  val segments = Await.result(waitAll(futures), waitTimeoutMillis millis)
```

but I'm still getting a TimeoutException, I guess because some of the futures haven't completed yet.
and that answer also states,

> Now Future.sequence(lifted) will be completed when every future is completed, and will represent successes and failures using Try.

But I want my Future to be completed after the timeout has passed, not when every future in the sequence has completed. What else can I do?

Comment: I think this is hard to do with pure scala futures since there is no "native" timeout handling in future api. Await's timeout won't do it. I think you should look into more complete "async" libraries that allow such processing. I can provide you an example in monix if you're interested

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc yes please provide an example with any dependency you think is best here, I'm looking for highly efficient code, my list of futures will be very big

Answer (score 1):

If I used raw `Future` (rather than some IO monad which has this functionality build-in, or without some Akka utils for exactly that) I would hack together utility like:

```
// make each separate future timeout
object FutureTimeout {
  // separate EC for waiting
  private val timeoutEC: ExecutorContext = ...

  private def timeout[T](delay: Long): Future[T] = Future {
    blocking {
      Thread.sleep(delay)
    }
    throw new Exception("Timeout")
  }(timeoutEC)

  def apply[T](fut: Future[T], delat: Long)(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext
  ): Future[T] = Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(
    fut,
    timeout(delay)
  ))
}
```

and then

```
Future.sequence(
  futures
    .map(FutureTimeout(_, delay))
    .map(Success(_))
    .recover { case e => Failure(e) }
)
```

Since each future would terminate at most after `delay` we would be able to collect them into one result right after that.

You have to remember though that no matter how would you trigger a timeout you would have no guarantee that the timeouted `Future` stops executing. It could run on and on on some thread somewhere, it's just that you wouldn't wait for the result. `firstCompletedOf` just makes this race more explicit.

Some other utilities (like e.g. Cats Effect IO) allow you to cancel computations (which is used in e.g. races like this one) but you still have to remember that JVM cannot arbitrarily "kill" a running thread, so that cancellation would happen after one stage of computation is completed and before the next one is started (so e.g. between `.map`s or `.flatMap`s).

If you aren't afraid of adding external deps there are other (and more reliable, as `Thread.sleep` is just a temporary ugly hack) ways of timing out a Future, like [Akka utils](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/futures.html#after). See also other questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615750/future-with-timeout-in-scala).

Comment: yeah, this is what i mean by `native` timeout. You need to block a whole thread to trigger a "timeout" exception. I don't think this should run in production like systems. This can exhaust your execution context and business logic will stop working because it waits on too many timeouts.

Comment: I agree which is why I added a disclaimer (if I am not allowed to use Akka, or Cats IO, or what not). Probably it would be ok most of the time, unless you would spawn too much waiting threads. But Akka with its `Scheduler` should be able to help with such cases, similarly IO monads. But these kind of questions I expect mostly from people who are stuck with raw `Future`s and cannot migrate to anything else because of company's/project's policy.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok thanks for the solution, but like you said it does seem very inefficient to create another thread for each of my futures. I can integrate any other dependencies so if you can provide a  solution with external library which is the most efficient and simple that would be most welcome!

Comment: Then take a look at `akka.pattern.after` if you want less invasive change. Or any IO monad which supports things like `IO.racePair` and `timer.sleep(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using [monix](https://monix.io/)

```scala
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler

val timeoutScheduler = Scheduler.singleThread("timeout") //it's safe to use single thread here because timeout tasks are very fast

def sequenceDiscardTimeouts[T](tasks: Task[T]*): Task[Seq[T]] = {
  Task
    .parSequence(
      tasks
        .map(t =>
          t.map(Success.apply) // Map to success so we can collect the value
            .timeout(500.millis)
            .executeOn(timeoutScheduler) //This is needed to run timesouts in dedicated scheduler that won't be blocked by "blocking"/io work if you have any
            .onErrorRecoverWith { ex =>
              println("timed-out")
              Task.pure(Failure(ex)) //It's assumed that any error is a timeout. It's possible to "catch" just timeout exception here
            }
        )
    )
    .map { res =>
      res.collect { case Success(r) => r }
    }
}
```

Testing code

```
implicit val mainScheduler = Scheduler.fixedPool(name = "main", poolSize = 10)


def slowTask(msg: String) = {
  Task.sleep(Random.nextLong(1000).millis) //Sleep here to emulate a slow task
    .map { _ =>
      msg
    }
}


val app = sequenceDiscardTimeouts(
  slowTask("1"),
  slowTask("2"),
  slowTask("3"),
  slowTask("4"),
  slowTask("5"),
  slowTask("6")
)

val started: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
app.runSyncUnsafe().foreach(println)
println(s"Done in ${System.currentTimeMillis() - started} millis")
```

This will print an output different for each run but it should look like following

```
timed-out
timed-out
timed-out
3
4
5
Done in 564 millis
```

Please note the usage of two separate schedulers. This is to ensure that timeouts will fire even if the `main` scheduler is busy with business logic. You can test it by reducing `poolSize` for main scheduler.